# Set Content View Crashing in ListActivity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am getting this error from the debugger:

> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10540): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is
>   'android.R.id.list'

My layout file is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#004D79"
    >
        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        />
        <EditText 
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
            android:text="EditText"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
            android:id="@+id/editText" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/skipButton">
        </EditText>
        <Button android:text="Skip"
         android:id="@+id/skipButton" 
         android:textSize="18dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_width="80dp">
         </Button>
    </RelativeLayout> 
</LinearLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

so for my list view do I still use listView = getListView();

Comment: if you extends ListActivity you need to give android:id="@android:id/list".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

declare  ListView id  as :

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

instead of

```
<ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        />
```

Comment: so for my list view do I still use listView = getListView(); ?